# Ajax toggle button state not changing after click/committing Rails 5.2 JQuery_ujs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I created a two state toggle button that switches based on the current boolean value. I have a destroy/update method listens for changes to the button state. The button itself, works in theory - as in, you can change its state, but it doesn't switch buttons until after a completely refresh the page

I tried changing the respond_to format to JS only. To see if the button would utilize the update.js.erb and destroy.js.erb actions. The button state still doesn't change. I am simply trying to swap the buttons in the show view to match true/false value changes with AJAX. Lastly, I created a helper method for the link_to button that has embedded AJAX within its conditional blocks. Doesn't work whatsoever.

## credentials_controller.rb

```
class CredentialsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_user_record

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_record.begin_credentialing!
       format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_record.end_credentialing!
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def load_user_record
    @user_record = UserRecord.find(params[:ece_form_id])
  end
end
```

user_records/show.html.erb

```
 <%= div_for @user_record do %>
    <%= link_to_toggle_user_record_credentialing(@user_record) %>
 <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :user_records do
  resource :credential, only: %w(update destroy)
end
```

user_records_helper

```
def link_to_toggle_user_record_credentialing(user_record)
    url = user_record_credential_path(user_record)
    if user_record.credentialing?
      link_to_with_icon('far fa-times-circle', 'End Credentialing', url, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        remote: true,
        class: 'credential bttn bttn-danger bttn-simple bttn-sm',
      })
    else
      link_to_with_icon('fas fa-star', 'Begin Credentialing', url, {
        method: 'PUT',
        remote: true,
        class: 'credential bttn-success bttn-simple bttn-sm',
      })
    end
  end

  def link_to_with_icon(icon_css, title, url, options = {})
    icon = content_tag(:i, nil, class: icon_css)
    title_with_icon = icon << ' '.html_safe << h(title)
    link_to(title_with_icon, url, options)
  end
```

update.js.erb

```
$('#user_record_<%= @user_record.id %> .credential').replaceWith("<%= j link_to_toggle_user_record_credentialing @user_record %>");
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$('#user_record_<%= @user_record.id %> .credential').replaceWith("<%=j link_to_toggle_user_record_credentialing @user_record %>");
```

user_record.rb

```
class UserRecord < ApplicationRecord
 def credentialing?
    is_credentialing != nil
  end

  def begin_credentialing
    self.is_credentialing = true
  end

  def begin_credentialing!
    begin_credentialing
    save!
  end

  def end_credentialing
    self.is_credentialing = false
  end

  def end_credentialing!
    end_credentialing
    save!
  end
end
```

Expected Behavior: Button state should switch and boolean value should change with AJAX

Actual Results: Button state only switches after refresh.

Comment: in which function you did write the script `document.on(ready...` ??

Comment: I think you need to reload the model in a success callback in your ajax. Since it's submitting via js, it's not going to reload the page, which reloads the models, afaik. Or reload the instance of the model in your js.erb